# menu items not working

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have created menu and submenu items of my application using DOJO framework. I can able to click the menu items and navigate to submenu items in chrome but in IE and firefox i could not able to click/choose the submenu item, when i click on main menu below is the error i'm seeing on the browser console when i run the application.Even chrome is showing the error message but still i can able to see the submenu items.
Error message:

```
TypeError: this._openPopup is not a function
this._openPopup();
```

code for menu.js:

```
.....
            dijit._MenuBase.prototype.onItemHover = function(item){
                    this.focusChild(item);
                    if(this.focusedChild.popup && !this.focusedChild.disabled){
                        this._openPopup(); //at this line it is showing the error.
                    }
                };
...
```

Please suggest, how i can resolve this?

Comment: You are probably in the wrong scope. Could you provide an jsFiddle example? And you are using Dojo in the wrong way. Take a look at dojo's `on` module and the `require` module.

Comment: @GuyT - http://jsfiddle.net/nw9tU/160/ . But in fiddle i could not able to display the menu items. But you can see my code in jsfiddle. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using Dojo 1.6 and not the newest(1.10 atm)? The syntax of the fiddle requires Dojo 1.7 or up(excepts the onItemHover, this is totally wrong).

Comment: @GuyT, sorry i didn't noticed, the version i'm using in my project is 1.9, updated with version http://jsfiddle.net/nw9tU/162/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nw9tU/164/ Does that fit your needs?

Comment: Yes, but menu items should be in horizontal line and when i click on main menu submenu items should be shown.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nw9tU/165/

Comment: Do not use frontend validation. This is a **huge** security risk. In your fiddle you are not filling the `permissionsArray`. Never use `dijit._MenuBase.prototype.onItemHover`. If you want an `itemHover` check at all costs, use the `on` module.

Comment: It is working when I comment out all the extra stuff: http://jsfiddle.net/nw9tU/169/ . The 'value' undefined exception you get is because the textbox 'rolesPermissionsStrings' isn't placed at the screen.

Comment: use http://jsfiddle.net/nw9tU/171/ Check properties of objects before you use them ;) I haven't did that in my example.

Comment: Note that I've put the `if` statement at the end. This will produce much cleaner and maintainble code. ps. Don't use '|' as menuseperators. Dojo has his own.

Comment: +1 for all your efforts, i will try and let you know if i'm going right.thanks.

Comment: and did you succeed?

Comment: @GuyT - Thanks for asking, it was browser issue. In IE8 the object was null. IE8 could not able to support the javacode which i have written in js file and so always the menu items are not enabled for the users.

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors. First of all you are including an old Dojo version. Your second mistake is that you do not set a 'placeholder' at the screen. You are calling the `placeAt` with an unknown id. You have to create a div with `id='wrapper'`.

Don't make Dojo harder than it is and use the given examples.

In the next fiddle I've fixed the fiddle(note that I changed the dojo version).

http://jsfiddle.net/nw9tU/168/